# one attribute referencing, attributes in two different tables

Tags: oracle

I have 4 tables

```
customer: CustomerID - primary key, name

Magazine: name - primary key, cost, noofissues

Newspaper: name - primary key, cost, noofissues

subscription: custID - references CustomerID of Customer, name, startdate, enddate
```

In the above, can I reference the `name` from `subscription` table to reference `name` from `Magazine` and `name` from `Newspaper`?

I have created the tables `Customer`, `Newspaper` and `Magazine`. I only need to create `Subscription`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE subscription (
  custID     INT
             CONSTRAINT subscription__custid__fk REFERENCES Customer( CustomerId ),
  name       VARCHAR2(50)
             CONSTRAINT subscription__mag_name__fk REFERENCES Magazine( Name )
             CONSTRAINT subscription__news_name__fk REFERENCES Newspaper( Name ),
  startdate  DATE
             CONSTRAINT subscription__startdate__nn NOT NULL,
  enddate    DATE
);
```

Yes, you can and you will have two foreign keys on the same column pointing to different tables but if the value in the column is non-null then it will expect there to be a matching name in both the magazines table and the newspapers table - which is probably not what you are after.

Can you have a foreign key that asks can the value be in either exclusively in this table or that table (but not in both)? No.

But you can re-factor your database so you merge the newspapers and magazines tables into a single table (which you can then easily reference); like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  CustomerID INT
             CONSTRAINT customer__CustomerId__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name       VARCHAR2(50)
             CONSTRAINT customer__name__nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Publications (
  id         INT
             CONSTRAINT publications__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name       VARCHAR2(50)
             CONSTRAINT publications__name__nn NOT NULL,
  cost       NUMBER(6,2)
             CONSTRAINT publications__cost__chk CHECK ( cost >= 0 ),
  noofissues INT,
  type       CHAR(1),
             CONSTRAINT publications__type__chk CHECK ( type IN ( 'M', 'N' ) )
);

CREATE TABLE subscription (
  custID     INT
             CONSTRAINT subscription__custid__fk REFERENCES Customer( CustomerId ),
  pubID      INT
             CONSTRAINT subscription__pubid__fk REFERENCES Publications( Id ),
  startdate  DATE
             CONSTRAINT subscription__startdate__nn NOT NULL,
  enddate    DATE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you can create a foreign key constraint on `subscription` that references either the `newspaper` table or the `magazine` table, the answer is no, you cannot.  A foreign key must reference exactly one primary key.

Since `magazine` and `newspaper` have the same set of attributes, the simple option is to combine them into a single `periodical` table with an additional `periodical_type` column to indicate whether it is a magazine or a newspaper.  You could then create your foreign key to the `periodical` table.

Although it probably won't make sense in this particular example, you could also have separate columns in `subscription` for `magazine_name` and `newspaper_name` and create separate foreign key constraints on those columns along with a `check` constraint that ensured that exactly one of the values was non-NULL.  That might make sense if the two different parent tables had radically different attributes.

Not related to your question but as a general bit of advice, I wouldn't use the `name` as the primary key.  In addition to being rather long, names tend to change over time and names aren't necessarily unique.  I would use a different attribute for the key, potentially a synthetic primary key generated from a sequence.